# R function getFilings() is saying 2019 and 2020 EDGAR data are not found

Tags: r, edgar

I am running the following R code to download filings for a specific year from EDGAR from the SEC website.  I am using the "edgar" R package.  I use the following code:

**output <- getFilings(cik.no = c(353905), "ALL", quarter = c(1, 2, 3), 2018, downl.permit = "n")**

This does get me the result I am wanting but it only seems to work for anything from 2018 prior.  When I try for 2019 or 2020 I get the following:

**No filing information found for given CIK(s) and Form Type in the mentioned year(s)/quarter(s).**

I get this notification even though there are filings on the site for those time periods.  Does anyone know why that would be?

Comment: You aren't specifying any cik.no

Comment: oops, I have edited in an example which doesn't work

Comment: Have you ran getMasterIndex for those years?  Maybe the index you have on your system is bad and needs to be refreshed.